# Can not load class "Kernel" from namespace "App"

Tags: php, symfony, yii, composer-php

I have a messy web application writen in Symfony and Yii.
stucture of application looks like:

```
|- app
|  |- app
|  |- src <code>
|  |  |-App
|  |- protected <symfony fw>
|  |  |-vendor
|  |- yii <yii fw>
|  |- composer.json
|  |- index.php
```

and `index.php` require `symfony.php`. and at that file, i new `Kernel` class. and it locales inside `src/App`. but when running, it throw code:

`Attempted to load class "Kernel" from namespace "App". Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel", "Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel" or "Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel"?`

My `symofony.php`

```
<?php

require_once  __DIR__ . '/../protected/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once  __DIR__ . '/../protected/Application.php';
require_once  __DIR__ . '/../protected/Environment.php';

use App\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

require __DIR__ . '/config/bootstrap.php';
if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
    umask(0000);

    Debug::enable();
}

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^ Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
}

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
    Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}

$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
```

The class `Kernel` is:

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Kernel\MicroKernelTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as BaseKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollectionBuilder;

class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;

    private const CONFIG_EXTS = '.{php,xml,yaml,yml}';

    private $files;
```

My `composer.json` at autoload:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "SCO\\": "src/",
            "App\\": "app/src/App/",
        },
        "classmap" : [
            "protected/components/",
            "protected/models/",
            "protected/modules/"
        ],
    },
```

you can see, namespace `SCO` actually cover the `App` in file directory view.

It work on my macbook (docker), but when i move to windows using xampp, it brokes

Comment: add symfony.php file contents to question. That is where you make use of kernel, right? 
where is symfony.php?

Comment: I'll ask the same question as the error message: "Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel"...?"

Comment: i 've updated the `synfony.php`.  yes i have requred the `autoload` and use ...

Comment: `"App\\": "app/src/App/"` From your project structure there doesn't seem to be a `app/src/App/` folder, only `app` and another one `src/App/`. Try `"App\\": "src/App/"` (and maybe `composer du`)

Comment: i changed, but still got that error @b

Comment: From this interactive debugging session here on SO, it is now for some hours that it manifests it has ended. We serialize guessing just on the platform to a related error message as we think [edit] is too late. Please see [help] for appropriate usage and further instructions. Thanks for flying with Symfony.

Comment: i 'm really sorry everybody, i for some reason, when migrate from mac -> win, some folder has been messied, that lead to unable to load it